# How to read the text inside a credential / UAC prompt?

Tags: powershell, uac, windows-11

Is there a way to read the text inside a credential / UAC prompt? The aim is to identify the name of the application which causes the UAC prompt.

In this attached image, the prompt shows up with name of the application which initiated it (outlook in this case). How to identify the application source with PowerShell or with any script? Already tried reading the auditing logs (event 4688), which was useful. However, that cannot specifically narrow down the source of the UAC prompt.

[image: Credential / UAC Prompt]

Comment: UAC is a security feature, so there are limitations what you can do programmaticly with it. What problem would knowing the prompting app name solve?

Comment: We want to automatically suppress UAC from a certain application in our environment. We have a tool which runs in the background to monitor the uac, if we can find the source application of the uac, we can suppress it

Comment: @Azure_CloudServices, have you tried turning on UAC auditing and reading the event logs as this [SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/273312/1796696) explains?  I would hope the logs would tell you which application is triggering it.

Comment: @Darin Yes. I tried enabling it. This enables logging with the event id 4688. With this, I am not able to find the source of the application which initiates / triggers the UAC

Comment: Am I missing something? The process triggering the UAC prompt is identified in the UAC prompt.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, I assume the intent is to get this information _programmatically_.

Comment: But for what _purpose_? What problem does it solve?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: See the OP's comment above (2nd comment overall).

Comment: My approach would be to deploy the application in a test environment, unit-test to determine what's provoking the UAC prompt, and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do it; but you shouldn't.

Normally the UAC prompt is shown on a secure desktop so that applications cannot read/write/programatically push buttons of the prompt (as it would defeat the entire point)

But for the purposes of screen-readers and the like, there are things you can do:

- first you have to manifest your application for `uiAccess`
- but in order for Windows to honor that manifest flag
- the application must be run from a *"protected location"* (e.g. `Program Files`)
- and it must be digitally signed

On top of that, User-Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI) prevents a "medium" integrity process from trying to send messages (e.g. `WM_MOUSEDOWN` `WM_GETTEXT`) to the "high" integrity UAC window

But if the program that is monitoring the screen for UAC prompts, running in Program Files, with `uiAccess` enabled, is also running as **administrator**, then you can programatically send `WM_GETTEXT` messages.

### But do the right thing instead

Instead of waiting for an application that has been manifested as `requireAdministrator` to show a UAC prompt when lauched: change it's manifest to run `asInvoker`.

That way it won't run as an administrator.